# Get-ADGroupMember : A referral was returned from the server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am getting a referral returned from the server when I run any command against another object in another domain than the machine it is connected to.

So I login with ID located on domain A and launch PowerShell with Administrator account residing in Domain B so when I try to run `Get-adgroupmember identity XXX  -server domainB` I receives referral error, even when I use server name or DC with Port number.. this issue start happening recently.

```
Get-ADGroupMember : A referral was returned from the server
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember -identity "XXXXX"  -server
XX.XX.XX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (nb it microbank admi:ADGroup) [Ge
   t-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : A referral was returned from the server,Microsof
   t.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try now

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like "XXX" } -Server domainB | Get-ADGroupMember -Server domainB
```

Comment: Thanks OWl but issue is with permissions not with how I execute  the powershell command. I used to ran the same command with no issue for some reason now I lost  my elevation access, I only ran commands under the domain that computer connected to. when I ran the command you provided  I get the same error. its  something related to UAC but I cant figure it out yet

Comment: i ran the command on powershell ise now issues  without running ad administrator are u a member of enterprise admin?

Comment: Yes,  nothing has change in my Access, this command use to work two days ago, I had a script that pull 9642 users and now for some reasons I get referral error every time ran command against ad object doesn't reside in the same domain as the computer the am running the command from

Comment: issue resolved after re-creating windows profile and re-permission my administrator ID in AD

Comment: Some issues are solved by doing what is least expected that will fix.